# How to reuse a UI element in react native

Tags: react-native

**App.js**

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,TextInput, View, Button, Text } from 'react-native';
import Toast from 'react-native-simple-toast';
import TextItem from '.src/Components/Textviews/TextViewDisplay';


export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
              placeName : "",
              titleText: "Text view"
          }

  placeNameChangeHandler = val =>{
   this.setState({
     placeName : val
   })
  }

  placeSubmitHandler = () =>{
    this.setState({
      titleText: this.state.placeName.trim() 

    })
    Toast.showWithGravity('This is a long toast at the top.', Toast.LONG, Toast.TOP)

  }

   render() {
      return (
      <View style={styles.rootContainer}>

        <View style={styles.btnEditContainer}>
          <View style ={styles.wrapStyle}>
          <TextInput
          style = {styles.textInputStyle}
          value = {this.state.placeName}
          onChangeText = {this.placeNameChangeHandler}
          />
        </View>
          <View style ={styles.wrapStyle}>
          <Button
          title="Add"
          style ={styles.buttonStyle}
          onPress ={this.placeSubmitHandler}/>
        </View>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.textContainer}>
          <View style ={styles.wrapStyle}>
            <Text
            style ={styles.textStyle}>
            {this.state.titleText}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>

        </View>
      );
   }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  rootContainer: {
    height:"100%",
    width:"100%",
    backgroundColor: "#008000",
    flexDirection:"column",
    alignItems:"center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  btnEditContainer: {
    backgroundColor:"#008080",
    flexDirection:"row",
    alignItems:"center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  textContainer: {
    backgroundColor:"#00FFFF",
    flexDirection:"column",
    alignItems:"center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    flexDirection:"column",
    alignItems:"center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    //flex:1


  },
  textInputStyle: {
    borderColor:"black",
    borderWidth:1,
  },
  wrapStyle: { marginLeft:5,
    marginRight:5 },
});
```

**TextViewDisplay.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';

const textItem = (props) => (
    <View style={styles.rootElement}>
        <Text style={styles.textItem}>
            {props.textItem}
        </Text>
    </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    rootElement : {
        backgroundColor:"red"
    },
    textItem : {
        color: '#f44336'
    }
});


export default textItem;
```

---

**What I am trying to do:**

1. Instead of Text in `App.js` file I have written a
   `TextViewDisplay.js` file to reuse.
2. How to properly implement in render function of `App.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I undrestood your query correctly, then you just want to replace this

```
<Text style ={styles.textStyle}>
    {this.state.titleText}
</Text>
```

from your `App` component with your `TextItem` (re-usable) component.

As you have already imported your `TextItem` component, you can do this way

```
<View style={styles.textContainer}>
    <View style ={styles.wrapStyle}>
        //This is your re-usable component
        <TextItem style = {styles.textStyle}>
            {this.state.titleText}
        </TextItem >
  </View>
</View>
```

And you just need to change `{props.textItem}` to `{props.children}` in your `TextItem` component.

```
<View style={styles.rootElement}>
    <Text style={{...props.style, ...styles.textItem}}> //Here you can get style from your parent component
        {props.children}   //This is the child element
    </Text>
</View>
```

**Note:** Always use `PascalCase` names for your component.

If you don't want to work with `{props.children}` and only want to work with `{props.textItem}`, in that case you need to pass props,

```
<TextItem style = {styles.textStyle} textItem = {this.state.titleText} />
```

Now you can use `{props.textItem}`,

```
<View style={styles.rootElement}>
    <Text style={{...props.style, ...styles.textItem}}> //Here you can get style from your parent component
        {props.textItem}  
    </Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple re using components in react native :

Step - 1 : Import the function to the screen where you want to reuse that.

ex : `import {textItem} from '../pathName'`

Step -2 :

```
render() {
      return (
//Create the component of the UI and then use it in render and don't forget to import that:

    <TextItem
    textItem = 'happy Coding'
     />
)}
```

Also make sure the component name starts with capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

Just import your component and instantiate it in any render function:

```
import textItem from './TextViewDisplay';

render() {
      return (
      <View style={styles.rootContainer}>
         <textItem textItem={'label'} />
         ...
      </View>
}
```

I would suggest defining the component upper camel case though:

```
const MyTextItem = (props) => (...)
```

And giving the property a more meaningful name:

```
<MyTextItem label={'label'} />
```

Finally, it's also good to define property types, so other users of your component known which properties to pass, and what type they should be. For example as such:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

MyTextItem.propTypes = {
  label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}
```

Comment: This is wrong `<textItem textItem={'label'} />`. React will not take it as a component.

Comment: It should, textItem is a functional component. What is your error?